# How do I install rosdoc_lite when using groovy?

Tags: ros, rosdoc, ros-groovy, rosdoc-lite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I install rosdoc_lite when using groovy? More specially I am using the Ubuntu 10.04 groovy installation (full desktop).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53874/how-do-i-install-rosdoc_lite-when-using-groovy?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, install that package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-rosdoc-lite
```

Then follow the [package documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdoc_lite).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-01-31**:
Thanks. Works but I noticed that comments from msg files are not included in the documentation as they were with rosdoc. And comments are missing in the doc on [www.ros.org](http://www.ros.org). I seem to remember some doc like the one for NavSatFix having more information before...

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-31**:
Your are right. That's unfortunate. Maybe we should open an issue ticket.

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-02-01**:
I added an issue in github for this.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-01**:
Thanks! For others reading this page, Tommy's issue is here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdoc_lite/issues/29